# Prevent zoom when textfield is selected

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Is it possible to force android not to zoom in when a text box is selected for typing?  I have written an html5 web app and the layouts look great until I click on the textfield to enter text.  Upon this action, android will automatically zoom in on the textfield.  Is there a way to prevent this?  Thanks!

My code for the webview is as follows:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebViewClient wv = new WebViewClient();
wv.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(myWebView, "http://urlgoeshere");
myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(wv);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://urlgoeshere");
```

My xml for the webview is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `setDefaultZoom()` if that's not necessary. That way your program leaves it to the phone to accommodate the page and won't force zoom-in